# Migrating Oracle's UNPIVOT to Postgres

Tags: sql, database-migration, common-table-expression, unpivot, postgresql-9.6

Error Message:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INCLUDE" LINE 2: ...S TIME_SUMMARY, VALUE AS _ FROM TIME_SUMMARY UNPIVOT INCLUDE

My Query:

```
WITH time_summary AS 
( 
       SELECT time_schedules, 
              model_anchor_week_desc, 
              start_date, 
              weekly_data, 
              notes 
       FROM   vw_wo_time_summary 
       WHERE  wo_id = 157 
       AND    version_major = 0 ) 
SELECT Replace(col, '_', ' ') AS time_summary, 
       value                  AS _ 
FROM   time_summary unpivot include nulls ( value FOR col IN (time_schedules, 
                                                              model_anchor_week_desc, 
                                                              start_date, 
                                                              weekly_data, 
                                                              notes))
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: You need to tell us what that query does. You can do that by editing your question and supplying sample data and the output based on that data. And why are you migrating to Postgres 9.4? That's a pretty old version.